# InnoDB / MySQL - new transaction uses old data on SELECT instead of returning updated data

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, transactions, innodb

1. Begin transaction Tx1
2. Tx1 performs a `SELECT`
3. Commit Tx1
4. Begin transaction Tx2 in a different session, using a different connection
5. Tx2 performs a `SELECT`
6. Update rows in Tx2
7. Commit Tx2
8. Begin a new transaction, Tx1
9. Perform select - get results from step 2(??)
10. Commit Tx1
11. Begin transaction Tx1
12. Perform select - get CORRECT results, i.e. the committed updates from Tx2

Very confused... How can this happen? It is happening reliably and consistently.

Comment: This can happen if 8 starts before 7 finishes and you are using an isolation level above `READ UNCOMITTED`.

Comment: This isn't the case :( 7 is definitely happening well before 8

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this can happen if the transaction isolation level is set to `REPEATABLE READ`. Set the transaction isolation level to `READ COMMITTED` and everything is hunky dory. Doesn't really explain why (must be some sort of BEGIN TRANSACTION hanging around?)

Comment: If this were true, it would be a bug. Also, `BEGIN TRANSACTION` automatically commits any previous transaction.

Comment: @MarcusAdams In JDBC, the transaction start is handled by the driver, not by the developer explicitly executing a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`.