# Knex+MySQL UPDATE then SELECT some times returns old values

Tags: mysql, knex.js

The following code *some times* returns old values from MySQL using Knex.js:

```js
await db.knex('table')
  .where('id', '=', table_id)
  .update({
    last_opening: db.knex.fn.now(),
  });

// ... removed another db.knex('table')...update() here for brevity, updating different fields

const updated_data = await db.knex('table')
  .where('id', '=', table_id)
  .select('last_opening')
  .first();

// At this point updated_data.last_opening randomly contains either the old or the new date
```

`db.knex` comes from another module like this:

```js
// package.json has "knex": "^0.21.1",
const knex_factory = require('knex');

exports.knex = knex_factory({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host : conf.DB_HOST,
    user : conf.DB_USER,
    password : conf.DB_PASSWORD,
    database : conf.DB_NAME,
  }
});
```

It seems to happen only in the production environment. Haven't been able to reproduce locally at all, and can't recall if I saw it in the staging environment.

```sql
$ SELECT @@TX_ISOLATION;
REPEATABLE-READ

$ SELECT VERSION();
5.7.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
```

This question [InnoDB / MySQL - new transaction uses old data on SELECT instead of returning updated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613500/innodb-mysql-new-transaction-uses-old-data-on-select-instead-of-returning-up) leads me to suspect this has to do with transaction isolation levels and Knex' connection pool, but I don't understand enough to comfortably change anything.

Can anyone help explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that code should / could ever return the old value unless you are running that code multiple times concurrently, when for example 2 request handlers may update the row one after another and then both are reading the last update from the DB.

Also if you have multiple processes running that code it could also cause that kind of behaviour.

If you wrap both queries to be in a transaction that should not happen even if updates are ran concurrently.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response at least! I would have deleted my question since the problem kept happening with a transaction still. I managed to reproduce locally and finally determine the underlying problem was something unrelated. :(